# Setting the default page in web.config is not working

Tags: iis, webforms

I'd like both `example.com/myRootFolder/` and `example.com/myRootFolder/Default.aspx` to displays Default.aspx located in the root folder.

So far, I'm still getting the `iisstart.html` page.

I've added this code to my web.config file, suggested everywhere, but I'm still getting the `iisstart.html` page.

```
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="default.aspx" />
    <add value="Default.htm" />
    <add value="Default.asp" />
    <add value="index.htm" />
    <add value="index.html" />
    <add value="iisstart.htm" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Thanks for helping